# Apache v2 - How to properly fulfill the license in a product

Tags: apache-2.0

Apache v2 specifies on point 4a:

> You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License

If one uses an Apache v2 library in a commercial product must one deliver the Apache license text together with the product? (if the product can't display the text)

Would it be enough to display the link to the Apache license in the product documentation?

Or should it display the whole text on the product webpage?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If one uses an Apache v2 library in a commercial product must one deliver the Apache license text together with the product ? (if the product can't display the text)

Yes. This can be as part of your commercial license agreement, documentation or in the product or else.

> Would it be enough to display the link to the Apache license in the product documentation?

That would not be enough. Put the whole text instead.

> Or to display the whole text on the product webpage ?

That would work.

Note also that there is can also be a notice. And you should also produce the notice.

And for an attribution to be complete you should also mention who and what you are attributing: e.g. typically at least the project name and copyright.

Comment: I see that both Apache and GPL require to **give** the recipient a copy of the license text. What I understand from this is that actually the license text should reach the user (website would not be enough). Is this correct ?                                 GPLv2 :  and give any other recipients of the Program a copy of this License along with the Program.
Apachev2:  You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License; and

Comment: The text of the GPL license should be with the code. In the case of Apache this is simpler to do the same. In fact my recommendation is to always include the full license texts of third-party code included in any software project, FLOSS or proprietary. This is simple and a no-brainer and meets this condition for all licenses.

Comment: True but if the license text is within the code, the 'normal' user would not be able to read it. I am worried that in court just delivering the text within the code might not be seen as fulfilment of the license conditions.

Comment: When I said with the code, I meant with the code be it source or binary ;)

Answer (score 1):

It's not really on topic but it's in the same area.

For GPLv2, here is a nice document:

https://www.linuxfoundation.org/news-media/research/practical-gpl-compliance

On page 4 we can see what **giving** the license means:

> When you distribute GPL code as binary or source code, you need
>   to ensure it is accompanied by a copy of the GPL license. This is the
>   easiest and quickest part of any GPL compliance engineering process.
>   You can include a copy of the GPL license as physical or digital
>   media along with a product. Some examples are:
>
> - Smart televisions that come with a copy of the GPL physically
>     printed at the back of the instruction manual along with
>     other legal notices.
> - Smartphones that come with a copy of the GPL under the
>     Settings > Legal menu or similar location.
>     The important objective is to ensure that the license is easily
>     discoverable by an interested party.

Comment: Can you provide a quote in your answer? Otherwise it is hard to make sense of things...